# WebKit: Is there any css trick to bring elements to front without scaling it?

Tags: css, webkit, z-index, rotation

From the picture, I use rotate3d() to the red rectangle so half of it is in front of black rectangle and the other is behind.

[image]

I want black rectangle to be front of red rectangle so I have to use translateZ() so it become

[image]

The problem is that I want black rectangle to be front without scaling it. I want black rectangle to still be the same size. Is there any trick? I tried z-index but it didn't work. I guess it because I use rotate3d().

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste the actual code for this here or put it in a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Here you are. http://jsfiddle.net/TPB7A/  If you want to get picture 2, change from translateZ(0px) to translateZ(100px).

Comment: @ScottS I forgot to add your name so it can notify you

Comment: When I look at your example fiddle in Chrome, the black is already above the red. What browser is showing your picture?

Comment: @ScottS Safari version 5.1.7 (should be latest version)

Comment: Interesting. I think what you are seeing relates [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339623/why-does-transform-origin-z-distort-on-safari-ios/10420268#10420268) that I answered (though the OP did not like my answer, but I still think the logic of my answer is sound, even if he rejected it). This would explain the difference between Safari and Chrome, since they seem to be applying `-webkit-perspective` differently.

Comment: @ScottS Thx. The simplest solution I know now is set -webkit-perspective to value 0. But this will make the rectangle does not have 3D look.

Comment: @chanok--yes, but that can be worked around. See my answer I just posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have access to Safari at present to test it in, so I leave that to you (let me know if it works), but I believe the following should work.

Since browser interpretation of `-webkit-perspective` seems to be the problem as [I noted in my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339623/why-does-transform-origin-z-distort-on-safari-ios/10420268#10420268), remove it from `#container` and replace it with `-webkit-transform: perspective(500)` and then add the same thing (`-webkit-transform: perspective(500)`) to both `#parent` and `#parent2` which is what I have done [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPB7A/15/embedded/result/).

The issue seems to be that Safari does not apply a perspective to the `#container` when using `-webkit-perspective` whereas Chrome does. It seems to be a matter of interpretation of the spec, as I discussed in answering [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339623/why-does-transform-origin-z-distort-on-safari-ios/10420268#10420268).

Comment: It works! Thx. So this mean that -webkit-perspective perform as it actually be 3D object but -webkit-transform: perspective(500) perform as the plain layer but represent the 3D object on that layer. Am I correct?

Comment: @chanok--the [spec page](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-3d-transforms/#perspective-property) says `perspective` is like `transform: perspective` only the first "applies only to the positioned or transformed children of the element, not to the transform on the element itself," while `transform: perspective` applies directly to the element. But there seems to be inconsistency in how it is implemented. I actually think Safari may be correct. We should not have had to add `transform` to `#container` because it should not have been applying `perspective` originally to that element itself based on spec.