# CSS3 translateZ doesn't work for chrome?

Tags: css

Following simple POC code's translateZ works on Firefox, but it doesn't work on Chrome. The translateX, translateY part works on both browsers. What is wrong with the code? Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        @-webkit-keyframes test1KeyFrames{
            from{
                -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
            }
            to{
                -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1000px) translateY(100px) translateX(100px);
            }
        }

        @-moz-keyframes mozTest1KeyFrames{
            from{
                -moz-transform: translateZ(0px) translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
            }
            to{
                -moz-transform: translateZ(-1000px) translateY(100px) translateX(100px);
            }
        }

        .test1{
             -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
             -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
             -webkit-animation-name: test1KeyFrames;    
             -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
             -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
             -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; /*cubic-bezier(0.16,0.74,0.22,-0.15);*/
             -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
        }

        .mozTest1{
             -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
             -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
             -moz-animation-name: mozTest1KeyFrames;    
             -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
             -moz-animation-direction: normal;
             -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; /*cubic-bezier(0.16,0.74,0.22,-0.15);*/
             -moz-backface-visibility: visible;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="border:1px solid red; -webkit-perspective: 100px; -webkit-perspective-origin:240px 140px; -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d; -moz-perspective: 100px; -moz-perspective-origin:240px 140px; -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;" >
        <div id="slider1" class="mozTest1 test1" style="border:2px solid blue; width:480px; height:280px; background:url(img3.jpg)">                
        </div>

        <image src="img1.jpg" class="test1 mozTest1"/>

        <p class="test1 mozTest1">Hello world</p>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are experiencing. It seems to work for me in Chrome, _however_ for me [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UJ2ub/) seems to start the animation in Chrome prior to the div actually being fully rendered to the screen so half or more is missed visually (Firefox seems to wait), whereas when I set a pause at the start [like this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UJ2ub/1/) Chrome behaves like Firefox. But `translateZ` appears to work on both.

Comment: Also note, your likely to experience rendering differences between Safari and Chrome using `-webkit-perspective`. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623479/webkit-is-there-any-css-trick-to-bring-elements-to-front-without-scaling-it/10672948#10672948) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339623/why-does-transform-origin-z-distort-on-safari-ios/10420268#10420268) for information I've discovered during other problems. The second post the OP (I assume) down voted my answer, but I'm still convinced I was on the right track in my logic even if he didn't accept it.

Comment: @ScottS translateZ doesn't work for me, my chrome version is "19.0.1084.52 m". Initially I thought it was because I turned off my graphical hardware acceleration but I tested on a normal PC, it's the same. It works on Firefox even I turned off hardware acceleration.

Comment: I'm on a Win7 machine also using "19.0.1084.52 m" and it was working as I noted. Strange.

Comment: I am also experiencing a difference between chrome and ff: http://jsfiddle.net/YcDpg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Win XP vs. Win 7 Difference

There is at least one other who experienced this difference between Win XP and Win 7 regarding `translateZ`, as [this issue report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92855&can=1&q=translateZ%20XP&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary) notes (though it was not resolved).

Whether the difference is a bug or a feature upgrade from a 32-bit to 64-bit system is unclear. In either case, there is probably not a solution you can do through your CSS coding to resolve it.